# What's wrong with my Android Studio Setup?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I'm completely new to `Android Studio`. I watched some YouTube videos to correctly install `Android Studio`. I downloaded `Android SDK` and `Java`. In the videos, after installing, they just press the New Project and start typing. When I press New Project, I got this. I mean, did I forget to do something? Is it this hard to create a simple Hello World program?

[image: this is what i get when i click new project]

Comment: Think about pressing next

Comment: Are you sure that this is [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) ?! Android studio does not include options for static web projects !

Comment: I do press next and Studio opens with lots of errors and nothing works. @Atef, yeah I did download from there.

Comment: @fahrettinpercin what is the version number? it is in the about sections under help menu

Comment: This is not `Android Studio IDE`. This is `Intellij IDEA`.

Answer (score 1):

your download is androidStudio or Intellij, My AndroidStudio like this
[image: here]

Comment: That's what I was expecting. But this window never shows up

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks like intelliJ. Did you get your Android Studio installer from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arise because the android studio did not detect your sdk files.Just press next till you somewhat reach the end of making a new project.Go to File->setting->Android SDK,then at the top you will see the android sdk location field,there select your sdk location,that's about it